# Is a form's "action" attribute useless when using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, ajaxform

For forms that are only submitted by AJAX, since the default HTML submission behavior is prevented, is there any benefit to setting the `action` attribute at all? I haven't found any AJAX-form instructional pages saying that it can be omitted, but I don't see the point in setting it, so I thought I'd ask. Is it only as a fallback if Javascript is disabled (that scenario is becoming increasingly rare, and my code would be pretty useless in other ways without JS), or is there some other benefit I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think, as you say, it's an historic fallback. The action attribute value might be used by the AJAX call, but that's just an implementation decision (and maybe not a good one). I think there are vanishingly few web developers who can write a non–trivial web application that is functional without javascript. That skill seems to be going the same way as accessibility (which is utterly broken on most web sites).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support fallback behavior, such as in the case that a JavaScript error prevents the JS submission, you'll want an `action` attribute. You don't necessarily need it otherwise, though.

One case where you may want it is if you're following “unobtrusive” methodology which encourages you to set the `action` when the form is rendered by the backend, then when you submit your form via JS (AJAX) you use the value of the `action` as the target of the request.

In any case, you always want to set the `method` on your form even when submitting via JavaScript; the default is `GET`, which results in the form values being submitted in the query string. When the request is made without TLS this information is transmitted in the clear, and even with TLS it ends up in the cache which can cause information to be disclosed (e.g. from a shared computer).